# Adding footer in an RML document

Tags: odoo, rml

I have a document in which I already managed to insert a header. The body starts after the header and continues on to next pages where my header is there.

That said, I am not able to properly add a footer. From checking the RML reference there seems to be no tag I can add that will act as a footer so I have to come up with a solution. So far nothing I have tried works. Here is my template section:

```
  <template pageSize="(595.0,842.0)" title="Test" author="geof" allowSplitting="20">
    <pageTemplate id="first">
      <frame id="first" x1="24.0" y1="-80.0" width="530" height="796"/>

          <header>
              <pageGraphics>
                  <image x="5.3cm" y="8.9cm" height="280.0">[[ get_background() ]]</image>
                  <image x="6.3cm" y="25.7cm" height="80.0" >[[ company.logo or removeParentNode('image') ]]</image>
                <!--  <drawString x="1.0cm" y="28.1cm">[[ company.name ]]</drawString>
                  <drawRightString x="20cm" y="28.1cm"> Reference Guide </drawRightString>
                  <lines>1cm 28cm 20cm 28cm</lines> -->
                   <drawString x="7.0cm" y="1.1cm" height="50.0">[[ get_footer() ]]</drawString>
              </pageGraphics>
          </header>

    </pageTemplate>
  </template>
```

Comment: may be helpful to you. http://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2014/12/how-to-display-custom-header-footer-in-all-pages-rml-report.html

Answer (score 0):

"-Go to "Settings" -Choose "Company"; select your company

You can customize the footer on the bottem field on the initial screen

-Choose the "Footer/header-text" tab

You can edit the header (and footer) text here; you can view your changes by using the preview button on the top right hand corner of this screen."

**UPDATE**:

**----------**

[how to add a user defined header in a rml report in openerp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947770/how-to-add-a-user-defined-header-in-a-rml-report-in-openerp)